# iframed page won't show video in chrome or safari

Tags: html, iframe, browser, cross-domain

I have an iframe that contains a page from a different domain.  That page has a video on it.  The video will play in firefox, ie and opera but not in chrome or safari.

Any ideas?

You can see what I mean here:  http://myawesomelinks.com/Links?id=2451
If you scroll down about half way, there is a video that works in firefox and ie but not in chrome.

Also the Disqus comments aren't loading on the bottom in chrome, that also works in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts"` parameter on your iframe is breaking functionality on the framed site.

Comment: okay... that code prevents sites from breaking the iframe.  Is there a way to use the sandbox for this purpose without breaking the functionality of the videos?